# Create new directory with files without copying or overwriting old ones? (Python)

Tags: python, directory

I'm working with many thousands of images held in a particular folder structure which is needed for certain image processing programs. There is a different program, however, that requires the images to be in a different folder structure. I can't change the programs, so what I do is just make the second folder structure out of the first one using copyfile from python's shutil module.

This works okay with small data sets, but my latest one is 12 gigs and it is so silly to have duplicates of everything. Is there a way to create multiple folders containing the "same" file?

Thanks so much!

Comment: what os you are using ?, if using linux [this may help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196537/how-to-copy-a-folder-structure-and-make-symbolic-links-to-files)

Comment: Windows 10... the programs themselves don't work on linux, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this is to simply make a symbolic link with the desired name.  This saves the trouble of consuming double disk storage.  In UNIX (Linux), the command is

```
ln -s <existing_dir_name> <desried_dir_name>
```

In Windows, you make a "short cut".

Comment: The key word that opens everything up for me was "symbolic link". Getting all sorts of results for that now! os.symlink tool looks like a one line fix.Thanks!

Comment: Yay!  You can also look into a "hard link".  That way, if someone deletes the original reference, yours would still be valid -- the files would not be deleted.  This will work only within the same file partition.